# Java Primefaces Datatable Column Values Calculation

Tags: java, primefaces

I am new to java. I try to make a web application. I use primefaces framework and dynamodb as database. In  my datatable, I want to calculate a dynamic column that shows the difference of dates "today" and the "variable date".

I can calculate the diffence between today and the variable date ("t_vekalet_trh") in managed bean. However, the "String difdaysevrak" is calculated same for every row. "dosyalar.getT_vekalet_trh()" has been taken from database table but not for every row in datatable. "25" value shown in the output pic is related to first row, but written in each row.

With my coding(I know it's so wrong), the difference is calculated just for the last row I edited, but I want to make this for each row. The related coding and the output is as below:

Bean:

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
@Data
public class DosyalarService implements Serializable {

  @Autowired private DosyalarRepository dosyalarRepository;

  private Dosyalar dosyalar;

  private List<Dosyalar> dosyalarList;
 private String difdaysevrak;

  public String getDifdaysevrak() {
    String aab;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (dosyalar.getT_vekalet_trh() == null) {
       aab=formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    } else {
       aab=formatter.format(dosyalar.getT_vekalet_trh());
    }

    String vektar = aab;
    String todaydate = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Date vekDate = null;
    try {
      vekDate = formatter.parse(vektar);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Date toDate = null;
    try {
      toDate = formatter.parse(todaydate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    long diffInMillies = Math.abs(toDate.getTime() - vekDate.getTime());
    long aaa = ((diffInMillies / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 365);

    long t1 = 1663240680000L; if ( t1 >= vekDate.getTime() && t1 <= toDate.getTime() ) {aaa = aaa -1;}

    this.difdaysevrak = String.valueOf(aaa);

    return difdaysevrak;

  }

  public void setDifdaysevrak(String difdaysevrak) {
    this.difdaysevrak = difdaysevrak;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<p:dataTable id="dosyalarListevrak" var="dosyalar" widgetVar="dosyalarListevrak1" value="#{dosyaListeService.dosyalarList}"
             style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word; zoom:80%" 
             scrollable="true" allowUnsorting="true" sortMode="simple" showGridlines="true"
             emptyMessage="Aradığınız kriterlerle veri bulunamamıştır." >


    <p:column headerText="E" style="width:5px">
        <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-user-edit" action="#{templateService.menu('dosyalarEdit')}" update="@this" ajax="false" styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-flat ui-button-plain" style="height:15px; margin:0">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dosyalarService.dosyalar}" value="#{dosyalar}" />
    </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="Dosya Bilgisi" sortBy="#{dosyalar.must_adi} #{dosyalar.must_soyadi}" filterBy="#{dosyalar.must_adi} #{dosyalar.must_soyadi}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="width:100px" ><h:outputText value="#{dosyalar.must_adi} #{dosyalar.must_soyadi}" /></p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="Temsilci" sortBy="#{dosyalar.dtemsadi}" filterBy="#{dosyalar.dtemsadi}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="width:100px"><h:outputText value="#{dosyalar.dtemsadi}" /></p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="Tür" sortBy="#{dosyalar.dtur}" filterBy="#{dosyalar.dtur}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="width:100px"><h:outputText value="#{dosyalar.dtur}" /></p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="Eksper"  sortBy="#{dosyalar.d_eksadi}" filterBy="#{dosyalar.d_eksadi}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:100px"><h:outputText value="#{dosyalar.d_eksadi}" /></p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="Sigorta"  sortBy="#{dosyalar.d_sigorta}" filterBy="#{dosyalar.d_sigorta}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:100px"><h:outputText value="#{dosyalar.d_sigorta}" /></p:column>
    <p:columns  headerText="Süre"  value="#{dosyalarService.difdaysevrak}" var="aaa"  style="width:100px"><h:outputText value="#{aaa}"  />  </p:columns>
    
</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the value when you create the list and forget about the service call inside the table.

```
<p:columns headerText="Süre"  value="#{dosyalar.difdaysevrak}"/>
```

Or, if you want to do it with the service, supply a parameter from the row to your service.

```
<p:columns headerText="Süre"  value="#{dosyalarService.difdaysevrak(dosyalar.aDate)}"/>
```